# Can I write same code Without finally block?

Tags: java

I know, that finally block is always executed even if exception occurs.

It doesnt execute if we use System.exit(0) in try or catch block;

It is used for releasing resources.

But I have question, the statements after catch block will anyways execute even if those are written without finally, right?

Please explain me.

See the following code snippets -

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

    Connection con=null;
    try {
        String url ="someURL";
        String user ="someUserName";
        String password ="somePassword";

        con=DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        .
        .
        .
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(con!=null) {
            con.close();
        }
    }

}
```

and

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

    Connection con=null;
    try {
        String url ="someURL";
        String user ="someUserName";
        String password ="somePassword";

        con=DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        .
        .
        .
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

   if(con!=null) {
     con.close();
   }


}
```

So my `con.close();` will execute anyways, then why I need finally?

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case I would say that this indeed is somehow identical, but have you considered a `try with resource` so that `con` is closed automatically? this would be the cleanest way I can think of.

Of course if something not as `Exception` is thrown (`Throwable` for example), then your connection would not be closed without a `finally` ...

Comment: Yes, using `try with resource` even `con.close()` is also not required.

Comment: @NinadPingale exactly! which makes the code cleaner, better and *far* more error-less prone

Answer (score 0):

Usually catching all exceptions with a catch block is not the best practice. In such a case, if any thing that is not caught is thrown, finally will be helpful. And, your 2nd code snippet will not work.

Comment: If exception occurs, it will be caught in catch block. and con.close will always execute. Right ?

Comment: yep. but it is not a good practice to cover the whole code with catch(Exception e)